# How to get Hour() of specified timezone in Go language?

Tags: go

When I use Hour() function, it keeps return the UTC hour. How to get the correct Hour number with specified Timezone? Thanks!

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `In()` function and it should work. For example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    loc, _ := time.LoadLocation("Europe/Berlin")

    t := time.Now().In(loc)
    fmt.Println(t.Hour())
}
```